# .submit() not working during $.ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm afraid I cannot post a jsFiddle to this question, and I believe it's simply a matter of not passing the correct parameters through the `success:` function, but a form that has this script running on it does not submit twice.

We are looking to submit the information to `email_script.php` via an ajax request, and then submit the information through the form's default `action` tag as well.

It submits the ajax request correctly, but then doesn't submit the second time (although the console does log a `succ = 1` to the `success: function()`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var dataObject = "email=web@ukipme.com&accName=accname&listName=listname";
        console.log(dataObject);
        $.ajax({
          url: "email_script.php",
          data : dataObject,
          type : "GET",
          success: function(){
            $("#subscribe_form").submit();
            var succ = "1";
            console.log(succ)
            alert('success');
          }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

**Form HTML:**

```
<form action="https://ukipmemail.com/interface/list.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="subscribe_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="accName" value="accname"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="listName" value="listname"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="fullEmailValidationInd" value="Y"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="doubleOptin" value="false"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value="NO-REDIRECT"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="errorUrl" value=""/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> I would like to register to receive news about Automotive Interiors Expo 2014
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label sr-only">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="web@ukipme.com" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" disabled>Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Additional Javascript used in file:**

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
    $('#submit').attr("disabled", !$('#checkbox').is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: You are calling `event.preventDefault()`, yet you are not passing the `event` in to the handler.

Comment: I wish I knew enough about jQuery to know what that means. Could you please elaborate in an answer, Rory?

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer as I'm not 100% it will solve your problem. However you need to include the event in the click handlers parameters in order to use `preventDefault()`: `$('#submit').click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); // rest of your code...`

Comment: You're not actually submitting the form in your first ajax call as you are hard-coding the values on page-load. Are there any values filled in in your form?

Comment: It is a form that has hard-coded inputs, and a checkbox that they confirm and then hit submit. Would I need to pass the checkbox's value through the ajax request too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stopped the submit event before performing the ajax request, therefore, to make the submit happen, you have to re-execute it. You did attempt to do that, however what you actually did was re-trigger the jquery submit event handler. To submit the form, select the form node and trigger it's submit method directly (which bypasses the jquery-bound event)

```
$(function() {
    $("#subscribe_form").submit(function(event) {
        var dataObject = "email=<?=$email?>&accName=<?=$accName?>&listName=<?=$listName?>";
        console.log(dataObject);
        $.ajax({
            url: "email_script.php",
            data : dataObject,
            type : "GET",
            success: function(){
                $("#subscribe_form").get(0).submit();
                var succ = "1";
                console.log(succ)
                alert('success');
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });    
});
```

I also switched to properly using the submit event, if you use click instead, users can bypass your click event handler by pressing enter on an input. Also, remove the id from your button(**VERY IMPORTANT!**) and make it a submit button.

Answer (score 1):

To trigger default form submission, use `[0].submit()` on the form's jQuery object, also remembering to pass event to the handler. It's always good practice to have `event.preventDefault()` at the top.

```
$(function() {
    $('#subscribe_form').submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var dataObject = "email=<?=$email?>&accName=<?=$accName?>&listName=<?=$listName?>",
        that = $(this);
        console.log(dataObject);
        $.ajax({
          url: "email_script.php",
          data : dataObject,
          type : "GET",
          success: function(){
            that[0].submit();
            var succ = "1";
            console.log(succ);
            alert('success');
          }
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Rather than listening for the click event on the submit button, it is better to listen for the submit event on the form. That way event.preventDefault() would work more consistently. I have cached the form jQuery object in the variable that and have used that in the success callback. I also added a semi colon after `console.log(succ)` - JavaScript does not require semi colons but the interpreter may run into issues sometimes. Always use it appropriately.

Comment: This method, as well as Kevin B's now throws a `uncaught type error: object is not a function` error (we believe is) on the `dataObject`.

Comment: Can you show us your form's HTML? The two are actually equivalent.

Comment: That's been added for you.

Comment: Great!! Could you please post the HTML passed to your browser by the server.

Comment: That would be more useful, huh? Sorry... amended.

Comment: HTML looks good. I doubt that dataObject line would cause that error; there's no method/function call on that line. It's got to be some other line.

Comment: Investigating, it's actually the `$("#subscribe_form")[0].submit();` line!

Comment: @mpdc you must have skipped over this part, :) *"Also, remove the id from your button(VERY IMPORTANT!)"* if you don't remove the id, .submit will reference the element with that id.

Answer (score 0):

Better usage As Rory mentioned in comment you are not passing the event object to the handler.

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
        var dataObject = "email=<?=$email?>&accName=<?=$accName?>&listName=<?=$listName?>";
        console.log(dataObject);
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: "email_script.php",
          data : dataObject,
          type : "GET",
          success: function(){
            $("#subscribe_form:submit").trigger("submit");
            var succ = "1";
            console.log(succ)
            alert('success');
          }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: This tidies the code, (although the form's default action wasn't happening anyway), and the ajax request still completes successfully... up until we ask it to submit the form. Still getting the same (non)action.

Answer (score -2):

Did u try to use .on() function?

```
$(document).on('click','#submit', function(event) {
```